# Ubuntu uses all upload speed

Tags: networking, server

So a couple days ago I received a complaint that there was really high latency on our network -- fine, easy fix. I open up our firewall to see that it's sending 100,000 packets per second! Our RAM and CPU were both at 99% (the highest I have ever seen them at). I figured out which box was causing the issue and turned it off immediately. I can't connect it to the internet or it will start WWIII on my network and I need to find out what is causing that many connections. I tried netstat -a but It does not show anything on pps, nor what application is causing it. I installed an application called GameCP on the server (and that's it) and it started doing this a day later, so I thought it was GameCP, but I stopped the service and it continues to do it.

Any help / suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Use [NetHogs](http://nethogs.sourceforge.net/) (package `nethogs`) to see wich process causes the traffic:

```
sudo apt-get install nethogs
```

Run nethogs with:

```
sudo nethogs
```

Comment: `htop` or `top` can also be used to find what it using the RAM and CPU - in `htop` you can use the tree view (by pressing t) to find what the parent process is as well. If possible you may want to unplug it from the network before starting it again.

Comment: @Wilf I second `htop` over `top` as it has got a more clearer view. :)

Comment: I can't connect to the internet or it will start using all of the bandwidth + CPU / RAM on the firewall.

Comment: You can cut the connection after a few seconds.

Comment: Tried nethogs and I can't get the program path. All it shows is: ... same thing for PID but it shows ? instead.